# How to add multiple custom-filter in Spring Security 3?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I need add two custom filters for FORM_LOGIN_FILTER, e.g.

```
<custom-filter after="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" ref="myUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter" />
<custom-filter after="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" ref="myUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter2" />
```

What I expect the filter sequences is:
1. Predefind FORM_LOGIN_FILTER
2. myUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter
3. myUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter2

But above will cause configuration error.
So, anyone knows how to write the right config?
Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do this:

```
<custom-filter after="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" ref="myUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter" />
<custom-filter before="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" ref="myUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter2" />
```

That should put them where you want them.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This could be a nice solution. 
But what if I want two add two or more custom filters between FORM_LOGIN_FILTER and BASIC_AUTH_FILTER? Is there any solution provided?
Thanks again.

Answer (score 56):

Use Spring's `CompositeFilter` to wrap your custom filters list, and then put that filter on relevant position on `SecurityFilterChain`.

E.g. like this:

```
<bean id="customFilters" class="org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter">
    <property name="filters">
        <list>
            <ref bean="myUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter"/>
            <ref bean="myUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter2"/>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
...
<custom-filter after="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" ref="customFilters" />
```

Comment: Glad there is a solution for this, but would be nice to allow bean refs instead of Enum values for before/after attributes

Comment: This is the right answer to the question and should e the chosen one. Thanks!

Comment: Correct answer, The filter beans can be configured with Request Matcher pattern as well

Comment: This must be the answer!

Answer (score 0):

I solved it like this:

```
public class QmLoginFilterWrapper extends GenericFilterBean implements ApplicationEventPublisherAware,
    MessageSourceAware
{
  private static final Logger                          LOGGER     = LoggerFactory.getLogger(QmLoginFilterWrapper.class);

  private List<AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter> filterList = new ArrayList<AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter>();

  @Override
  public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, final FilterChain chain) throws IOException,
      ServletException
  {
    FilterChain filterChain = new FilterChain() {

      @Override
      public void doFilter(ServletRequest arg0, ServletResponse arg1) throws IOException, ServletException
      {
        chain.doFilter(arg0, arg1);

      }
    };
    Vector<FilterChain> filterChains = new Vector<FilterChain>();
    filterChains.add(filterChain);
    if (LOGGER.isDebugEnabled())
    {
      LOGGER.debug("Filtering {} filters", filterList.size());
    }
    for (final GenericFilterBean filter : filterList)
    {
      final FilterChain lastChain = filterChains.lastElement();
      FilterChain loopChain = new FilterChain() {

        @Override
        public void doFilter(ServletRequest arg0, ServletResponse arg1) throws IOException, ServletException
        {
          if (LOGGER.isDebugEnabled())
          {
            LOGGER.debug("running filter {}", filter.getClass().getName());
          }
          filter.doFilter(arg0, arg1, lastChain);
        }
      };
      filterChains.add(loopChain);
    }
    filterChains.lastElement().doFilter(request, response);
  }

  @Override
  public void setMessageSource(MessageSource messageSource)
  {
    for (MessageSourceAware filter : filterList)
    {
      filter.setMessageSource(messageSource);
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void setApplicationEventPublisher(ApplicationEventPublisher applicationEventPublisher)
  {
    for (ApplicationEventPublisherAware applicationEventPublisherAware : filterList)
    {
      applicationEventPublisherAware.setApplicationEventPublisher(applicationEventPublisher);
    }
  }

  public List<AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter> getFilterList()
  {
    return filterList;
  }

  public void setFilterList(List<AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter> filterList)
  {
    this.filterList = filterList;
    Collections.reverse(this.filterList);
  }

}
```

Then in the context XML i have:

```
  <bean id="qmAuthFilter" class="com.qmplus.common.logon.QmLoginFilterWrapper">
    <property name="filterList">
      <list>
        <ref local="samlProcessingFilter" />
        <ref local="usernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter" />
      </list>
    </property>
  </bean>
```